# Tall tulip very close to concrete slab

Tags: trees, roots

I have a very tall tulip tree abt 18” from my family room and patio’s concrete slab. So far so good. Do I have to worry? I’ve been told that Tulip’s put down a large deep central root and there doesn’t seem to be too much disturbance ...

Comment: How long has the tree been in situ?

Comment: I have a 15" diameter oak 30" from the patio, I recently dug down 2 ft at the edge of the patio and cut every root going toward the patio.  I can't say it helped but I feel better. Twenty two years ago it was a broom-stick that was left for me by the contractor as a joke. I never thought an oak would grow that fast.

Answer (score 1):

No, worry is the wrong word, perhaps concerned is more appropriate. Eighteen inches is very close to a building for any tree or even shrub come to that. Tulip tree (also known as yellow poplar) is not known for being an unreliable tree so it is not likely to suddenly crash on your house or lift concrete. However it is known to be a fast growing tree producing a light wood, and this speed of growth will quickly require you to look again at the tree. For now it is giving you shade and I'm sure the flowers are wonderful.

Ease your mind by inviting some local tree guys to come and give you an estimate for removal. You will learn a lot from speaking with them and form your own idea of when to remove this one and plant another one to take over but somewhat further away from your buildings.